# Is there a trick to deploying Commerce Kickstart 2

Tags: commerce

When I deploy my commerce kickstart 2.0 site, it doesn't display correctly.  Namely, it doesn't seem to be using the themes.  But really, I am not sure what is going on.  I have done development using Acquia Dev.  I exported my database using the Backup and Migrate module.

This is the site
http://twelvebasketstech.com

I can't even log in, but it is accessing the database because I see some of my product categories.

I am using PHP 5.4.  The server is running the following: Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix)
Server version: 5.5.42-cll MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I have set the sites/default/files folder to chmod -R 775

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing display/designs/CSS rules are typically a symptom of missing stylesheets or other CSS style rules. If you browse to your login page, Drupal reports many errors about not being able to create files.

[image]

It looks like your intuitions are likely correct; the server is probably having trouble writing aggregated CSS files to the files dir. Try turning off CSS/JS aggregation to confirm this. If that fixes it, check ownership of the files dir/subdir to make sure it's the same owner as the web server process.

Comment: Thank you and God bless!  The issue was the CSS/JS aggregation, not permissions on the folder. For some reason aggregation wouldn't work on the webserver when I deployed it.